# X is suddenly using :1 instead of :0

Tags: x11, xorg

I am using Linux, a Debian derivate, Pop! OS to be precise.

My DISPLAY variable reads `:1` instead of the well-known `:0`.

Normally that shouldn't be a problem, but it is in my special case since I am rewriting an application for a special hardware where only one display is allowed and they hardcoded `:0` in lack of a deeper understanding. I am aware, thats a problem, but it would make my life so much easier if I could just use `:0` for now.

**How can I bring that back? How can I tell Xorg to create Display `:0` when starting up instead? The problem is not solved after rebooting.**

I think the problem first appeared after sharing the `/tmp/` folder with a docker container to allow using the host X server. But now it persists. There is no `/var/log/X*` log around, but there is a `~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log` (none for 0).

I didn't think `/tmp` was rebuilt on reboot, but I've now changed that to be sure that it is rebuilt each time. Unfortunately no change - I'm still getting `:1`. Running `ls -ld /tmp/.X*` gives me

```
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root 4096 Jul 21 20:41 /tmp/.X11-unix
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root 4096 Jul 21 20:17 /tmp/.XIM-unix
```

Comment: that should never be a problem. In fact, if it becomes a problem, that points to an underlying problem. What's the thing you're solving?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) explain what these "special" applications are because that really seems strange, they should be reading the DISPLAY variable and ii) tell us a bit more about your system. For starters, what operating system is this? If Linux, which distribution? How are you starting your X session? Are you using a graphical login manager? Are you starting it manually? Does this problem persist after a reboot?

Comment: I can imagine you're inadvertently launching two X.org's in succession, the first one could be crashing and the second one works. Could be something totally different, no idea. Check `/var/log/X*log`

Comment: I added additional information

Comment: Are you certain the docker container isn't running be default docker usually auto starts containers on reboot?

Comment: yeah I am pretty sure, I removed all images and all containers, even the stopped ones.

Comment: @roaima I don't think so. The command gives drwxrwxrwt 2 root root 4096 Jul 21 20:41 /tmp/.X11-unix
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root 4096 Jul 21 20:17 /tmp/.XIM-unix

Comment: @roaima I now mounted /tmp as a tmpfs and therefore it should be empty on every boot, unfortunately nothing changed

Comment: what I never recognized since now: even my desktop icons are gone, like if they where on another screen

Comment: Please add your own updates to the question. It's too easy to miss an important detail buried in a comment thread

Comment: I will do that.